# Subscript Problem in Markdown Using MathJax

Tags: markdown

I am using a MathJax script in Squarespace Markdown to code for math:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=default"></script>
```

In any display, I am able to code for the first set of multi-character subscripts (requiring braces), i.e., the first line, displaying as normal math, however, when I code for the second set of multi-character subscripts (requiring braces), i.e., the second line, the math is not displayed, only the code.  Single character subscripts (not requiring braces) are no problem.

> \[A_{1,2}=B_1\] displays as normal math
>   \[A_{1,2}=B_{3,4}\] yields [A{1,2}= B{3,4}], i.e., does not display

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to not have issues when copying you code. However, there was a difference in my referred JavaScript for the MathJax.

Within my HTML head, I have the following,

```
  <script id="MathJax-script" async
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
  </script>
```

Here is how your code was rendered....

[image]